# ANTLR4 grammar regex and tilde

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I want to have an ANTLR grammar for CSV input.

1. What's the difference between `(~["])+` and `(~['"'])+` ?
2. Why `~` is important?

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar Exercice4;

csv : ligne+
    ;


ligne : exp (',' exp)* ('\n' | EOF)
  ;

exp : ID
    | INT
    | STRING
    ;

INT : '0'..'9'+;

ID : ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;

STRING : '"' (~["])+ '"';

WS : [ ,\n, \t, \r] -> skip;
```

Comment: 1) There should be no difference 2) `~` negates the following item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a lexer rule, the characters inside square brackets define a character set. So `["]` is the set with the single character `"`. Being a set, every character is either in the set or not, so defining a character twice, as in `[""]` makes no difference, it's the same as `["]`.

`~` negates the set, so `~["]` means *any character except `"`*.

Comment: Is there a reason for ANTLR to not simply reuse the RegExp ^?